# Animate fxFlex width change after sibling container is removed

Tags: angular, animation, flexbox, css-animations

I have a simple layout which consists of two columns (side panel and content) as illustrated in the demo. When the side panel is removed via angulars `:leave` animation, the other container will stretch to `100%` width from `65%`. This is done via the `fxFlex` attribute. What happens here is that when the animation for the side panel starts the content is already stretched to 100% and when the animation finishes content will make an ugly jump.

When I try to animate the transition, animations always runs *after* the jump or just completely breaks the layout. Same happens if I try to delay the transition via css or directly with timeout in my component.

As an alternative I tried to animate the side panel to zero width. In this case it sorta worked, but the jump still happened, only this time it was during the `:enter` transition (the animation was completely ignored).

How can I make the transition smooth?

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-39tlpt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's what you wanted.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2p2kg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

The trick is that `flex` doesn't allow you to deal with `width`. Therefore, I concentrated on changing `flex` values as well as removed transitions and left it all to angular to handle.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
      trigger('slidePanel', [
        state('leave', style({
          flex: '0 0 100%'
        })),
        state('enter', style({
          flex: '1'
        })),
          transition('* => leave',
              animate('300ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)' ),
          ),
          transition('* => enter', 
          animate('400ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)'),
          )
      ]),
    ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  public panelShown = 'leave';

  public toggle() : void {
      this.panelShown = this.panelShown === 'enter' ? 'leave' : 'enter';
  }

}
```

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" class="fullScreen">
  <div [@slidePanel]="panelShown" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxFlex="35" class="green fullHeight">

  </div>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="content" [fxFlex]="100">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start" class="blue">
    </div>
    <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle panel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work, however I had to animate visibility as well since if the element has any padding or content it will stay there, but you put me on the right track - thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not satisfied of the result but you can do it without angular animation:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" class="fullScreen">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" [style.transform]="panelShown ? 'translateX(0%)': 'translateX(-100%)'" fxFlex="35" class="green fullHeight">

  </div>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="content" [fxFlex]="100"
  [style.min-width]="panelShown?'65%':'100%'">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start" class="blue">
    </div>
    <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle panel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in you css:

```
.content {
  transition: 2s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
}

.green {
  background: green;
  transition: 2s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1);
}
```

What's important to notice:

- `fxLayoutAlign="end center"`
- `[style.transform]="panelShown ? 'translateX(0%)': 'translateX(-100%)'"`
- `[style.min-width]="panelShown?'65%':'100%'`

[Working DEMO](https://angular-d93ive.stackblitz.io)

Comment: That's also my current version; I wonder there is no native solution for angular/flex-layout animations.